# Capture "screenshot" of Flex Display Object created with ActionScript but not added to stage

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

Is it possible to create a display object in AS and take a screenshot of it as ByteArray or whatever without adding it to stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with any DisplayObject using BitmapData http://blog.728media.com/tag/bitmapdata/ . Note that in Flex, components that have not been added to the stage may not lay out properly until you give them a width and height and call validateNow() on them.